# multicast network based on bridges between two hardware servers

Tags: linux, vps, bridge, multicast

```
+------------------------+   Internet     +----------------------+
|  Server_1              |       |        |     Server_2         |
| VPS1 ---- br0  __      |   (router)     |               __ VPS4|
|                  \ IP1 |       |        | IP2          /       |
| VPS2 -- br1  ---- eth0 +-------+--------+ eth0 --- br0 -- VPS3 |
+------------------------+                +----------------------+
                        ( cable connection )
```

Is it possible to create multicast network between VPS1, VPS3 and VPS4?

Server1 and Server2 are Linux server (Ubuntu OS is prefer)

Do you have some ideas how to implement this network arch?
Is it possible to create multicast network between VPS1, VPS3 and VPS4?

Server1 and Server2 are Linux server (Ubuntu OS is prefer)

Do you have some ideas how to implement this network arch?

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram is slightly unclear - I'm assuming that the two Ubuntu hosts are each connecting to the "router" device, which provides L2 and L3 connectivity.

Anyhow - if the various VM's are on the same subnet (likely) then multicast will work between the hosts.  Apart from making sure that multicast support is enabled on the guest operating systems there isn't a whole lot to do. If these VM's were, instead, on different L3 subnets then you'd need to make sure that the router supported multicast routing.